# iOS Distribution certificate missing from Visual studio 2019 Xamarin Apple Accounts, it is in apple developer account, provisioning profile imported

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, certificate, app-store

I was following [the guide on how to release the Xamarin app to Apple Store](https://instabug.com/blog/how-to-release-xamarin-app-ios-and-android/)
I have made a Certificate for iOS distribution and profile

[image]

[image]

Then followed the steps from [Microsoft on how to integrate this with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?tabs=windows)

I have added my Apple account successfully to Visual Studio 2019
[image]

It does show the provisioning profile, but not the certificates like it is displayed in the guide.
[image]

worse yet if I try to manually download the certificate and `Import Certificate`, the downloaded certificate has extension `.cer` while import is restricted to  `.p12`

[image]

**I have a feeling that I have missed a step or something?**

Comment: Download the `certificate` and  the corresponding `provisioning profile` manually , and then  double click on the files to install on mac , after that it should be listed in the menu .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT Hi Colex, thanks. It wasn't as easy as download and double click, but indeed adding certificate and profile to MacBook that is used as a connected device for developemnt, did the trick. Could you post this as an answer so I could accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the `certificate` and corresponding `provisioning profile` from dev site ,and install them into mac, after that it should be listed in the menu .

Comment: This question pertains to Visual Studio on Windows.